# Is there an intuitive reason for why this theorem is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Theorem: Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ we can always obtain a symmetric, positive definite matrix $S\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ by defining $S:= A^{T}A$

Question: is there an intuitive reason(i.e. not a formal proof) for why this theorem is true?

Comment: Positive definite is not always possible.

Comment: The best you could expect is that it is positive *semidefinite*, not **definite**

Answer (score 4):

This isn't true. Consider $A=0$ for instance.

That said, $A^TA$ is always positive semidefinite, because $x^TA^TAx=\|Ax\|_2^2\ge0$ for every real vector $x$.

$A^TA$ is positive definite if and only if $A$ has full column rank.

Comment: This is an intuitive reason?

Comment: @DouglasMolin No, there isn't any intuitive reason why the said theorem is true, because the theorem statement is false.

Comment: Looking forward to seeing if you have an intuitive reason for the semidefiniteness. I guess I'll have to create a new question for that, or else you won't answer it.

Comment: @DouglasMolin For semidefiniteness, yes, I think the reason given in my answer is intuitive enough. A real quantity is nonnegative because it is a perfect square. I don't think you can get a simpler explanation than that.